# How to use a method in the Main component on another

Tags: reactjs, localforage

I am trying to save notes into `localStorage` (or in this case `localforage`). I have a simple text area with a button called "save." The save button is located in another file indicated below.

I used an example found [here](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#data-api-setitem) to try to set the items.

This is the code I wrote:

```
  SaveMessage() {
    var message = <Notepad></Notepad>;
    reactLocalforage
      .SetItem("Message", message, function(message) {
        console.log(message);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

The var message is something I'm not too sure of either. Notepad is another component with the code which contains the text area and buttons:

```
      <div className="button-container">
        <button
          className="save-button"
          onClick={() => {
            props.onSaveMessage(saveMessage);
          }}
        >
          Save
        </button>

        <button className="remove-button">Show all</button>
      </div>
```

The area where it says `onClick` I was hoping there would be a way to use the `SaveMessage` method with `localforage` initially I tried creating it as a prop (from a tutorial) so in the main method I'd have:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Notepad onSaveMessage={this.SaveMessage}></Notepad>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and then on the Notepad component:

```
      <button
        className="save-button"
        onClick={() => {
          props.onSaveMessage();
        }}
      >
        Save
      </button>
```

When I click the save button on my application I am hoping something will be set within the local-storage on the browser, but I get an exception:

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

The error occurs when I set item on the save message code above and when I try to call it as a prop `onSaveMessage(saveMessage)`.

Comment: Next time you ask a question about React, instead of adding several little snippets, create a "minimal, reproducible example" of your situation. If you don't know how to create one check the section: ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added enough code to be able to fix your exact issue, but I can help you understand how you should proceed to fix it. In React when you want to share information between components, you need to `lift` that data into a parent component, and then share it through props. If your component tree is profound, then this task can get tedious. So several libraries have been developed to manage your app's state.

I suggest you start by reading ["Lifting State Up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) from the React docs page. To help you apply these concepts to your current situation, I've created a `CodeSandbox` in which I try to replicate your situation. [You can find it here.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lifting-state-ssd0p)

Once you understand the need to "lift" your state, and how you can share both data and actions through `props` you can migrate to state handler tool. Some of them are:

- [`React Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- [`Redux`](https://redux.js.org/)
- [`MobX`](https://mobx.js.org/)

There are much more. It is not an extensive list, nor the best, just the ones I have used and can vouch that they can help you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey guzmonne thanks for your reply, yeah sorry im new to using stack overflow but next I'll ask a question properly. I'll have a read of lifting the state later today and see what happens thanks for taking your time once again